# Customizing UITableViewCell in Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

In two classes, I've subclassed UITableViewCell in order to do some major customization. I'd like to use a Xib file to keep the amount of UI layout code to a minimum. I'm coming across an odd exception:

```
if (!cell) {
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        cell = [[[SearchCellTop alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
        NSArray* objects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SearchCellTop" owner:cell options:nil];
        cell = (SearchCellTop*)[objects objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    else {
        cell = [[[SearchCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
        NSArray* objects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SearchCell" owner:cell options:nil];
        cell = (SearchCell*)[objects objectAtIndex:0];
    }
}
```

This seems to work well for loading the Xibs. However as soon as I try doing something such as:

```
if (indexPath.row < [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section])
    ((SearchCell*)cell).Product = [products objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

I get -[UIAccessibiltyBundle setProduct:] unrecognized selector sent to instance

Everything indicates that 'cell' is of the correct type, however I'm stilling getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

From Apple's developer documentation for the `+ (BOOL)loadNibNamed:(NSString *)aNibName owner:(id)owner` method:

> owner
>
> > The object to assign as the nib FIle's Owner. If the class of this object has an associated bundle, that bundle is searched for the specified nib file; otherwise, this method looks in the main bundle.

In your case, the owner should be nil (or a specific bundle, if associated).

In the code, change the calls to the loadNibNamed method as following:

```
NSArray* objects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SearchCellTop" owner:nil options:nil];

NSArray* objects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SearchCell" owner:nil options:nil];
```